# Can Linq in .net be considered Internal Domain Specific Language?

Tags: linq, dsl

I am trying to understand what DSLs are, and just now this questions popped out of my mind. Atleast the fluent version seems to be internal DSL. What about the **query syntax of LINQ**. Can that also be called **internal DSL**? Or **External DSL**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Or at least the query syntax and keywords can.

*Linq* covers a few related technologies, and much of them can be understood just as a domain-specific classes and methods, just as most classes and methods are specific to some particular domain. It would be hard to argue that any of that constitutes a DSL when it's much the same as any other .NET code.

But the query syntax and keywords in C# and VB come up only in the context of the domain of queries against sources of data and differ from the rest of those languages, so it's reasonable to consider them internal DSLs. (It's possible to do strange things to make them serve other purposes, but it's possible to do strange things with other DSLs to force them into serving other domains too).